# add a value to column E if Column A has a value >0 on the same row VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, conditional-statements

How can I add a Cell Value from another Sheet to a Column E as long as the Cell in Column A is >0. I need it to move down a Row if true and end or 'go to line' if = 0?

Sheet1 has the one Cell needed for the Copy and Paste Value.
Sheet2 has a Table that spans from Column A to Column E.

This will be Looped through many Workbooks and there are an unknown amount of Rows.

I am using Excel. How should I start this VBA. I can't seem to figure out how to drop down a row for both columns.

Any and All suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: **How should I start this VBA**: You should start with research. Break your problem into multiple, practical, parts. Then tackle one part at a time. All of the individual parts have already been asked here and have working solutions under them. You are expected to show some effort

Comment: You will probably want to start with the workbook loop. Then your row loop. Then your criteria statement (`If A > 0 Then...`) and so on.

Comment: You'll need to know about For Loops: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html, then the cells formula style: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells and lastly IF statements https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php Websites chosen basically at random, just find ones with those search terms that work for you